# Perl: WWW::Google::CustomSearch: Missing required arguments?

Tags: perl, google-api, google-search-api

(2024-03-01 update: following question was misleeding. This bug was already reported to the maintainer and I found a workaround. Please see the comments)

I'm writting a script to run the Google Custom Search API to obtain the search results.
When I run the following script, it succeeds to get the result.

```
#! /bin/perl

# minisearch.pl

use strict;
use warnings;
use WWW::Google::CustomSearch;
use Data::Dumper;
use feature qw(say);

my $engine  = WWW::Google::CustomSearch->new(
    api_key => 'my api key',
    cx => 'my search engine ID',
    dateRestrict => 'm3',
    #siteSearch => 'accesswire.com',
    #siteSearchFilter => 'i'
    );

my $result  = $engine->search('mobile+pc+linux');

exit unless defined $result;

say "kind: ", $result->kind;
say "totalResults: ", $result->totalResults;
say "formattedTotalResults: ", $result->formattedTotalResults;
say "formattedSearchTime: ", $result->formattedSearchTime;
say "searchTime: ", $result->searchTime;
say "url_template: ", $result->url_template;
say "url_type: ", $result->url_type;
say "";
say "request:";
say "REQUEST:\n", Dumper $result->request;
say "";
say ">>> 10 pages >>>\n";
for my $n (1..2) {
    say "=== PAGE $n ";
    say "ITEMS:\n", Dumper $result->items;
    say "";

    sleep 10;
    $result = $result->nextPage->fetch;
}
```

But when I use `siteSearch` and `siteSearchFilter` parameters to restrict the target sites, it fails.

```
my $engine  = WWW::Google::CustomSearch->new(
    api_key => 'my api key',
    cx => 'my search engine ID',
    dateRestrict => 'm3',
    siteSearch => 'accesswire.com',
    siteSearchFilter => 'i'
    );
```

The following error message is displayed.

> $ ./miniSearch.pl Missing required arguments: totalResults at
> /usr/local/share/perl/5.30.0/WWW/Google/CustomSearch/Request.pm line
> 30.

I have added totalResults hash entry to new as below.

```
my $engine  = WWW::Google::CustomSearch->new(
    api_key => 'my api key',
    cx => 'my search engine ID',
    dateRestrict => 'm3',
    siteSearch => 'accesswire.com',
    siteSearchFilter => 'i',
    totalResults => 1000,
    );
```

or below.

```
my $engine  = WWW::Google::CustomSearch->new(
    api_key => 'my api key',
    cx => 'my search engine ID',
    dateRestrict => 'm3',
    siteSearch => 'accesswire.com',
    siteSearchFilter => 'i',
    totalResults => '1000',
    );
```

But the error remains the same.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: I suspect this is slightly misleading. I think maybe what it's saying is, that the result doesn't have the totalResults param. Now my vague understanding could be that if its the last page of results (or only one page), maybe it doesn't contain that. So it could be an issue with the Perl implementation. See if you can debug the actual request, and what response is incoming, and if it has totalResults in there.

Comment: The failure comes from creating a Page object. Page objects are created from responses. So, it seems that Google used to return a field it no longer returns, and the modules expects that field to be present in the response. Report the bug.

Comment: Someone reported [this issue](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=141609) for queries without results. Maybe leave a comment there?

Comment: You are aware that you have a hanging comma in your hash assignment?

Comment: @Bork, Trailing commas are perfectly fine. (And using them is my preferred practice.)

Comment: @ikegami  
You are right.  
My question above was misleading:  
(wrong) If you use siteSearch hash key, the search will fail with Missing... error.  
(right) If the searched sites are zero, the search will fail with Missing... error.

Comment: When I run the code below:

    my $engine  = WWW::Google::CustomSearch->new(
        api_key => 'my api key',
        cx => 'my search engine ID',
        dateRestrict => 'm3',
        );

    # Following words have not been found from the Google Web search
    my $result  = $engine->search('no_such_words_are_there_foo_bar_baz_');

The code failed with the same error.

Comment: For now, I have take this workaround:

    my $result;
    eval {
        $result  = $engine->search('no_search_result_found_foo_bar');
    };
    if ($@) {
        say "no search result";
        exit;
    }

For me, it's fine.
Thanks.

Comment: I have confirmed that the module has been fixed and now it returns friendly result even if the result is ZERO.
https://metacpan.org/release/MANWAR/WWW-Google-CustomSearch-0.40
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Being the author of WWW::Google::CustomSearch, I just pushed the proposed fix to the related issue.

https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=141609

The v0.40 has the fix.

https://metacpan.org/release/MANWAR/WWW-Google-CustomSearch-0.40

Comment: Thanks to your update, I have confiirmed that the module works fine and returns the friendly result even if the searched pages were zero.